# I have my data in HDFS. In order to retrieve data in KIBI it should be stored in ElasticSearch (Document database).

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hdfs, kibana

My question is will the data duplicated ?  Is there any other way to connect both without elastic search in order to remove duplication. we are working on Bigdata if it is duplicated it will cause storage issues ? Can anyone suggest the best tools which can perform Drill Down visualization like KIBI on Bigdata